# Picture not going into MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI

Tags: android, image, android-intent, camera, gallery

I have an issue that is only occurring on my tablet; Nexus 7 6.0.1
It is not present on my phone; Galaxy S6 5.0.2

I have a method to grab all images on external sd, as follows

```
private ArrayList<String> getAllImages(Activity activity) {
    Uri uri;
    Cursor cursor;
    int columnIndexData;
    listOfAllImages = new ArrayList<>();
    String absolutePath;
    uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME};

    cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

    columnIndexData = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        absolutePath = cursor.getString(columnIndexData);
        listOfAllImages.add(absolutePath);
    }

    listOfAllImages.add("camera"); //this is where the 'take picture' will be

    Collections.reverse(listOfAllImages);

    Log.d(TAG, "images " + listOfAllImages.toString());
    cursor.close();

    return listOfAllImages;
}
```

I kick off a photo-capture intent like this

```
Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
getActivity().startActivityForResult(takePicture, 1);
```

Then in the result, I just call a setup method that calls the above "get all images" function again, and then select position 1 which is the newly-taken picture. It works fine on my phone but not tablet. If I take a picture with the normal Camera app on the tablet, it shows up in "listOfAllImages"... but not when executing the intent.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d(TAG, "Take Picture result. " + requestCode + " " + resultCode + " " + data);

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        //means we took a picture, and the result was good
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                setupGalleryView();
                imagesGridView.performItemClick(
                        imagesGridView.getAdapter().getView(1, null, null),
                        1,
                        imagesGridView.getAdapter().getItemId(1));
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "activity result, camera, exception " + e.getMessage());
                app.showAlertDialog(context, "There was a problem obtaining image data.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Not entirely sure what to search for, so Google/other SO posts haven't been too helpful. Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: If you restart your app, will it show the picture?

Comment: @greenapps nope, never shows up. It's like the image capture from "ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE" just goes nowhere on the tablet.

Comment: Does it finally show up in Gallery app?